# Generating random not overlaping circles inside polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, polygon-creation, random, circle

How to generate random circles with certain radius size that do not overlap, inside a polygon?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Create `random points in polygon` and set a minimum distance.

Comment: @Babel: then do a buffer and select the circles that are entirely within the polygon.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

1. Create an image with a cell size equal to the circle radius.
2. Create an empty point vector file with the required CRS (the same as the CRS of the image).
3. Use the [r.random](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.random.html) tool located in the GRASS toolbox.
4. Use the [buffer](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisbuffer) tool with the distance value equal to the image cell size.
5. Use select by location tool to select all circles that lays within your polygon.
6. Inverse selection and delete all circles that lays outside of the polygon.

Answer (score 2):

### In this solution : circles won't overlap but they can touch

Let's assume there is a polygon layer called *'poly_test'* with several features in it, see image below.

[image: input]

**Step 1.** Firstly make use of the ["Create grid"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#create-grid) geoalgorithm

**Please, keep in mind:** Horizontal spacing = Vertical spacing = 2 * of the certain radius. So the radius of a circle in this example will be 10000/2 = 5000, that be later proved with this expression :

```
distance(centroid($geometry), point_on_surface(boundary($geometry)))
```

[image: window1]

[image: step1]

**Step 2.** Use the ["Extract by location"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#extract-by-location) geoalgorithm with *'are within'* geometrical predicate

[image: window2]

[image: step2]

**Step 3.** Proceed with the ["Geometry by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) geoalgorithm

```
make_circle(centroid($geometry), distance(centroid($geometry), point_on_surface(boundary($geometry)))/sqrt(2), 36)
```

[image: window3]

[image: step3]

**Step 4.** On the last stage apply the ["Random extract"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#random-extract) geoalgorithm

[image: window4]

and get the output like this :

[image: step4]